# Defining a dict with a tuple singleton key

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

To define a singleton in python use singleton = ('singleton'),
A Python dictionary can use a tuple as a key, as in

[('one', 'two'): 5]

But is it possible to do

[('singleton'),: 5]

Somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this — but not with `('Singleton')`. You've got to use `('Singleton',)`.

The reason for this is that Python will interpret single parentheses around a single item as merely the item itself. Adding a comma enforces the tuple interpretation.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[('Thing')] = "one"
>>> d.keys()
['Thing']
>>> d[('Thing',)] = "another"
>>> d
{'Thing': 'one', ('Thing',): 'another'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Signify to python that 'singleton' is a tuple to make it work:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a[('singleton',)] = 5
>>> a
{('singleton',): 5}
```